# Getting Check Boxes to "Check" with VBA Conditionally

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the a box in golden column of check boxes, that you can see on the Left, to check if a date in the corresponding column is present under Original plan and a box in the white column of check boxes to check if a date is present in the corresponding column under Updated Estimate.

Very new at this and I've been playing around with it for a while and can't get it to work right.

Here is the sheet i am talking about:
[image: Here is the sheet i am talking about]

Comment: Since this is tagged with VBA, I'm assuming you would like help with your code. If you could add a recent coding attempt/example into your question, you'll be more likely to get answers. This is because the your code tells us: 1) what you've tried that hasn't worked. 2) approximately what your level of understanding is. 3) that you aren't expecting us to write all your code for you.

Comment: We need more information... are the checkboxes Form Controls or ActiveX? Are you able to iterate them or that's what you need help with? Which part are you stuck at, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These resemble ActiveX checkboxes, so that's what this answer is going to apply to. If this isn't the case, then hopefully this will still help someone else 5 years from now.

Anyway, Let's say you named the checkbox `cb_A1` for left checkbox and `cb_B1` for the right. You can change the value of these checkboxes by appending the [Sheet's Codename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) before the checkbox name. Example:

```
Sheet1.cb_A1.Value = True
' ^^^   ^^^
'  |     ↳ Name of Checkbox
'  ↳ Sheet's Codename
```

Since your image didn't include the column headers, let's assume **Orginal Date**'s column was `E`. You can perform your check in this column as such:

```
If IsDate(Sheet1.Range("E1")) And Sheet1.Range("E1").Value > 0 Then 
    Sheet1.cb_A1.Value = True
Else
    Sheet1.cb_A1.Value = False
End If
```